# Advice on my pong code

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am doing a clone of pong. It is just a barebone version of pong. And It would be nice if you guys could help me refine it. I am mainly doing it as a learning exercise, So i have just kept it to a basic functions.

```
import time
import pygame

done = False
pygame.init()
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)

screen_size = [320,240]

white = [255,255,255]
black = [0,0,0]

gutter = 10
score_1 = 0
score_2 = 0
ball_pos = [160,120]
ball_vel = [1,1]
paddle_1 = [0,0]
paddle_2 = [screen_size[0]-5,0]
vel_1 = [0,0]
vel_2 = [0,0]
P1 = False
P2 = False

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
pygame.display.set_caption("mygame")



while not done:
    time.sleep(0.02)
    screen.fill(black)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                vel_2[1] += 2
                P1 = True
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_UP]:    
                P1 = True
                vel_2[1] -= 2
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_s]:
                P2 = True
                vel_1[1] += 2
            if pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_w]:
                P2 = True
                vel_1[1] -= 2

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if(P1):
                vel_2 = [0,0]
                P1 = False
            if (P2):
                vel_1 = [0,0]
                P2 = False

    if ball_pos[1] in  range(paddle_1[1],paddle_1[1]+30) and ball_pos[0] in  range(0,gutter+10) :
        ball_vel[0] *= -1
    if ball_pos[1] in range(paddle_2[1],paddle_2[1]+30) and ball_pos[0] in  range(310,320):
        ball_vel[0] *= -1

    if ball_pos[0] > 320:
        score_1 += 1 
        ball_pos = [160,120]
    if ball_pos[0] < 5:
        score_2 += 1 
        ball_pos = [160,120]
    if ball_pos[1] > 230 or ball_pos[1] < 5:
        ball_vel[1] *= -1

    paddle_1[0] += vel_1[0]
    paddle_1[1] += vel_1[1]
    paddle_2[0] += vel_2[0]
    paddle_2[1] += vel_2[1]

    ball_pos[0] += ball_vel[0]
    ball_pos[1] += ball_vel[1]


##    pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(gutter,0),(gutter,screen_size[1]))
##    pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(screen_size[0]-gutter,0),(screen_size[0]-gutter,screen_size[1]))
    pygame.draw.line(screen,white,(screen_size[0]/2,0),(screen_size[0]/2,screen_size[1]),1)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen,white,ball_pos,10,0)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,white,[paddle_1[0]+5,paddle_1[1]],[paddle_1[0]+5,paddle_1[1]+50],gutter)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,white,paddle_2,[paddle_2[0],paddle_2[1]+50],gutter)
    label_1 = myfont.render(str(score_1), 1, (255,255,0))
    label_2 = myfont.render(str(score_2), 1, (255,255,0))
    screen.blit(label_1, (100, 100))
    screen.blit(label_2, (220, 100)) 
    pygame.display.flip()




pygame.quit()
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that you should improve in your code:

## 1) Constants vs Variables

When you define

```
white = [255,255,255]
black = [0,0,0]
```

you should instead do:

```
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLACK = (  0,  0,  0)
```

Constants should usually be created as `tuples` so that you do not mistakenly change their values. Also, since you only ever read a constant and never change its value a `tuple` is more appropriate. It also runs slightly faster

## 2) Creating Classes

Whenever you make a game, it is recommended that you create the objects as classes. In this case, you would have classes such as `Player` and `Ball`. In these classes you can define functions such as `update` and `draw`. This will allow you to easily draw an object or update its location, speed etc by a single line of code. Eg:

`player.update()`

`player.draw()`

`ball.draw()`

## 3) Time vs Timer

Instead of using `import time`, I recommend that you use the pygame built-in `Timer` option for controlling the FPS of the game. Here's an example:

`timer = pygame.time.Clock()`

then at the start of your while loop, you can simply do:

`timer.tick(60) #if you want 60 to be the number of frames per second`

I know it is a lot to take in but in the end the effort will be more than worth it and it will make future game making with pygame much cleaner.

[GREAT RESOURCE BOOK](http://inventwithpython.com/makinggames.pdf)

HAPPY PYGAMING!

Answer (score 1):

Try to encapsulate the ball and the paddles in proper Ball and Paddle classes. This way, you make your code cleaner and more reusable, since both paddles will share the same code.